# Proper Celery Monitoring and File-Management with Web-Services

Tags: python, django, celery, monitoring, file-management

We are working on an Internet and Intranet platform, that serves client-requests over website applications.
There are heavy-weight computations on database entries and files. We want to update the state of those computations via push-notification to the client and make changes to files without the risk of race-conditions. The architecture is supposed to run on both, low- scaled one-server environments and high-scaled cluster environments.
So far, we are running a *Django* Webserver with *Postgresql*, the Python-Library *Channels* and RabbitMQ as Messagebroker.

Once a HTTP-Request from a client arrives in Django, we trigger the task via *task.delay()* and immediatly return the *task_id* to the client. The client then opens a websocket to another Django-route and hands over the task_ids he is interested in. Django then polls the state of the task via *AsyncResult(task_id).state*. Once the state changes, we read the results via *AsyncResult(task_id).get* and push the *task_results* to the client.

Here a similar sequence diagramm, from another project I found online.
[Source](https://blogs.cisco.com/developer/johann03)(18.09.21)

Something that is not seen on the diagram, the *channels_worker* have to *fetch* the file they are working on from Django. A part of the result is not for the client, but to update the file. Django locks and updates the file localy as soon, as the client asks for and  Django receives the *task_results* from celery (the changes only add attributes and will not be in conflict with each other).

My thoughts about this architecture are:

- monitoring of the celery-events is bad so far.
- It is only triggered by the client, which has to know about the tasks to begin with.
- Django is not suited for monitoring
- and polling is not efficient in general.
- The file management seems fishy.

I would prefer a proper monitoring, where events are pushed to Django and the client. The client have to be able to consume the events at any time later.

I have some thoughts about solutions, but I would like to hear your opinion first. Later I can bring them in the discussion too.

Greetings
Python

### Edit 1

From other sources I got helpful information regarding a good strategy.

Instead of Django "monitoring" the celery tasks, we can use a dedicated Websocket-Service, like FastAPI thand monitors task events and propagates them to the clients via websocket.

The client doesn't have to know about it's running tasks per se. Instead we can have ownership of tasks and the client only has to authenticate himself. The whole Security Blog will be implemented anyways and its supported by Celery.

For the file management, we should use a dedicated object storage like minio. This service can become subscriber to task-events related to files.

Answer (score 0):

We all like Python, but we don't have to re-invent the wheel whenever we want a better monitoring or more control on the behavior of our systems.

That being said, I would recommend re-architecture the solution to decrease the complexity of your django application by exploring what native cloud solutions are offering in terms of micro-service architecture (API-Gateway), AWS SQS and SNS, computation, and storage options for your files.

Such an approach will carry out a lot of the monitoring, configurations, file management activities, and most importantly your monolithic application could scale without code changes or additional configurations.

Comment: Hey there, that is a good point. I'll see into getting a proper file management tool running. Everything else would be, as you said, inventing the wheel new.
When it comes to AWS, SQS and SNS.. am I right with the assumption, those are Cloud-Services?

Unfortunatly we cannot host our services on big cloud service provider. We have to able to work on our own servers.